# Interface Builder doesn't work

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface, sdk, builder

I have a trouble with Interface builder: I downloaded the iPhone SDK 4 but Interface Builder doesn't work: when I open it, it close immediately. What can I do???

Comment: You description doesn't give much to work with. Try looking in the console log to see if anything is logged there which might help isolate the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a re-install of Xcode and the SDK to see if that clears the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the new xcode 4 release is quite buggy. Not only that fails but a lot (and read me well, A LOT!) of other *features* are either buggy or non-working at all. There is also another bug when you assign a class to an IB object:

- Select the object,
- Click on the Identity Inspector,
- Type the name of a newly created class.
  IB does not assign that class to your object. Type anything else, say asdfghjk and IB will take it as a valid class name for your object (what!?).

So yeah, I made the mistake of replacing my xcode 3.5 and now I'm in the work of re-downloading it to go back to that version. I guess is as a friend of mine always says: "never, ever, use versions x.0 and doubt on x.1's"